# php mysql return code instead file

Tags: php, mysql, file

I got a little issue in my PHP.

The aim is to create a mySQL database and than create the PHP pages to upload, list and download files.

The mySQL, upload and list pages are fine, but when I try to download I get, instead of the file, the source code, or nothing at all.

Can you help me seeing my mistake?

This is the script of read.php (for the file list)

```
<html>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<title>Carica file nel database</title> 
</head> 

<p><b>Clicca su uno dei seguenti file</b><p><p></p> 
<?php 
include ("config.php");
include ("menu.php");

// connessione e selezione del database
mysql_connect('localhost', $userdb, $passdb)
or die('Connessione non riuscita: ' . mysql_error());

if(!mysql_select_db($database))
die('Selezione database fallita!');

// query per ottenere l'elenco dei files nel DB
$query = "SELECT * FROM data";

$risultato = mysql_query($query)
or die('Query non valida: ' . mysql_error());

// se ci sono files nel DB
if(mysql_numrows($risultato))
{
    // estrazione dei risultati e stampa dei link ai files
    while ($tmp = mysql_fetch_array($risultato))
    {
        echo "<p><a href=\"mostra.php?id=$tmp[id]\">$tmp[titolo]</a></p>\n";
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<p>Nessun file presente nel database</p>';
}
?>

<body></body>
</html>
```

while the mostra.php (means "show" in Italian), which should make me download the file, is:

```
<?php 
include ("config.php");
include ("menu.php");

// connessione e selezione del database

mysql_connect('localhost', $userdb, $passdb)
or die('Connessione non riuscita: ' . mysql_error());

if(!mysql_select_db($database))
die('Selezione database fallita!');

// query per recuperare il file

$query = 'SELECT file FROM data WHERE id = '.$_GET['id'];
$risultato = mysql_query($query) or die('Query non valida: ' . mysql_error());
$tmp = mysql_fetch_array($risultato);

// invio una intestazione contenente il tipo MIME
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$tmp[titolo]\"");

// invio il contenuto del file
echo $file;
?>
```

Comment: I'd like to recommend you to change the `mysql_*` for `mysqli_*` (http://br2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: Adding to the above comments of using PDO instead of mysql_* functions, also please be aware that a user can modify your complete database through SQL injection, because you do not validate the $_GET['id'] in your mostra.php! Please be aware and do not use the above code in production.

Comment: Learn how to use variables in strings:
`"<p><a href=\"mostra.php?id=" . $tmp['id'] . "\">" . $tmp['titolo'] . "</a></p>\n"`

Comment: Array elements need quotation marks: `"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $tmp['titolo'] . "\""`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `readfile()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

```
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Also turn `$tmp[titolo]` into `{$tmp['titolo']}`

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$tmp['titolo']}\"");
```